# What is impulse response (or equivalently the frequency response) of the channel ?

Tags: impulse-response

Please allow me to ask this silly question. I googled, but I still not clear about this. What is impulse response of a channel (wireless communication channel). Someone can explain me with a lot of pictures? I know this question is too ez, but I really need to understand it fully. Thank you again.

Comment: if your construction of the wireless channel is simply the physical empty space between two points, then its impulse response will be a **delayed space-time impulse** as there'r no reflections, no multipaths, no energy storage etc.

Comment: this is the very center of any communications textbook, and reading the first few chapters of one will not only give you an answer, but will also show you the other things you'll need to know to successfully deal with channels. I don't think there's a *shortcut* to be taken here – get a good text book, and read it.

Comment: I've once written an [illustration about multipath](http://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/multipath-propagation-and-its-effect-on-audio.html?rid=so9) channels, maybe this can help you?

Comment: oh, thank you. allow me to check this now.

Comment: Hey, Maximilian. I am reading your notes, not finished yet. But I just want to say, your article is really awesome. very clean and clear. Very good one.

Comment: Hi, Maximilian, would you help me about this question? Thank you in advance.http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40202/why-do-we-need-fft-pairs-for-ofdm

Answer (score 6):

This is a fundamental topic and it needs a lot of explaination.
I suggest you use the fading channel object of MATLAB, especially the **Channel Visualization Tool**.

There are lots of examples with visualization in this link. [MATLAB channel OBJECT](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/fading-channels.html)